# project hdf file with geospatial_lat and lon in batch process

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, batch, geolocation, hdf

Is there any way that I can do a batch process in projecting hdf files wherein I could get and include only the geospatial_lat and lon in the batch script since every hdf file have different geospatial extent.

Comment: Have you tried `gdalwarp -geoloc` on the subdatasets of the hdf? If it works manually, you can put it into a batch file as well.

Comment: Does having an unknown projection will affect the output? I have tried the `geoloc` but the output was divided into three and it has big spaces between each of the divided image. I don't have any idea what is causing these spaces.

Comment: The output does not have to be continuos. Think of aerial/satellite imagery taken during orbiting around the Earth. This may cover only a limited part of the globe, according to the flight route and sensor width.

Comment: @AndreJ - Thank you for that wonderful explanation. I just want to know after doing this process, does this mean the output file is already projected or not?

Comment: Assuming the geolocation is given in lat/lon, the output will be in EPSG:4326. If you want another CRS, you have to add `-t_srs` with the target CRS you want.

Comment: Sorry for not making it more clear with regards to what I mention with the images with spaces. After using the geoloc I tried merging the warped images but then the output image has spaces.

Comment: I guess you see something like this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143545/facing-a-problem-when-re-projecting-a-file . Otherwise please insert a picture in your question. Or maybe ask a new question about that.

Comment: What kind of hdf files are these (hdf5, hdf-eos, etc.), and what program/language are you looking to use for batch processing? Also, if you're working with NASA data, why didn't you just have them reproject it for you when you ordered it?

Comment: @AndreJ When I tried to review my question and checked the gdalinfo it wasn't the geoloc_extent that I was looking for, it was the geospatial extent instead. My mistake. How will I include the geospatial_lat and lon of each hdf4 files?

Comment: This is what I used in warping my files. `gdalwarp  -ts 2488 2141 -overwrite -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te 109.975 3.475 135.025 25.025 HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:@file:37` I have observed that setting the same extent for all the hdf4 files(to limit the size) in this batch process resulted to a clear pixelated images and an error like this appears `ERROR 1: Too many points (440 out of 441) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.`, which resulted to a black image only. That's why the merging process was also affected.

Comment: It might be that the source data is not north-up, but rotated against the North axis. In this case, the coordinates of the corners do not match with the extent coordinates anymore in an easy way. It would help if you add the gdalinfo data in your question.